# pycrypto encrypting private key with public key and then decrypting causes garbage

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, pycrypto

I was trying to make secure socket connection but when i
create private key and create pubkey out of private key
and create another private key then encrypt another private key with pubkey and decrypt it with first
private key gives me garbage

```
priv_key=RSA.generate(1024)
pub_key=priv_key.publickey()
another_priv_key=RSA.generate(1024)
priv_key.decrypt(pub_key.encrypt(another_priv_key.exportKey('PEM'),32))

output:b')O\xa5\xf9\xa5k%z\x10S.\x13\x06@\x83i\x1eI\xc6R\x1a\xa5}{h\x9aW0R\t\xa9\xf1\xdb\xe3\xdc\x1b\xd0\xe54\xb1\xf0^\x93 \xb6\x93\x16\xed\x98d8\xec6\xe2B\xde\x87(\xf7\xce\x9a)\x99ZR\xae$T\x1b\x19<\x12e\xfc\xd4\x92\xf3\x82l\x81ed,\xf4{CH\xe0\xd2\xdb\x0b#\xde9: ?\xea\x99\xe9\xd8\xe6\xca\xadFs\xa6\xc6\xc9x#\x96h\xf0\x83\x7f\xd25\xa4)Iv\xa6]\x15%5\x96'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to encrypt a plaintext that is far too long. RSA with a 1024-bit modulus should just about manage a string of 128 characters, but your ASCII-armoured private key will probably contain something closer to 1000 characters.

You can encrypt the key in separate pieces if you like.

```py
>>> priv_key.decrypt(pub_key.encrypt(another_priv_key.exportKey('PEM')[:128],32))
'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICXQIBAAKBgQCgoIPQspwO6DdHc9nGN6r9+qlMpFP+0PCik4QjbRzktX2U98sy\n2hZKXTjEj02+/bhJGL8dP63JDJQBWNL'
```